# Why does my `default_socket` value change when switching users?

Tags: php, macos

I am running MacOSX 10.10.5. I'm using a homebrew installation of MySQL and the default installation of php.

When I run `php -i` as my own user, I get the following output for `mysql*.default_socket`:

```
mysql.default_socket => /var/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/mysql/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_socket => /var/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/mysql/mysql.sock
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/mysql/mysql.sock
default_socket_timeout => 60 => 60
```

This is incorrect; my `mysql` setup creates the socket at `/tmp/mysql.sock`. But when I switch to the root user (via `sudo su`) I get this output for `php -i`:

```
mysql.default_socket => /tmp/mysql.sock => /tmp/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_socket => /tmp/mysql.sock => /tmp/mysql.sock
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/mysql/mysql.sock
default_socket_timeout => 60 => 60
```

My `/etc/php.ini` is setup with these values:

```
default_socket_timeout = 60
pdo_mysql.default_socket=
mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Clearly, when I am `root`, php is picking the values from `/etc/php.ini`. Otherwise, it is not. I've confirmed this using `php --ini`. **How do I get PHP to always pickup configuration values from `/etc/php.ini`?**

Comment: When running as your non-root user, what is the output from `php --ini`? How does it differ from root's output?  Do you have a user ini file? http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php